# How to tell Numpy to print time in UTC and not local timezone?

Tags: python, string, numpy, timezone

How to tell Numpy to print datetime64 in UTC and not in local timezone?

For example, I get:

```
>>> np.datetime64('2012-01-01T00:00Z')
Out[111]: numpy.datetime64('2012-01-01T02:00+0200')
```

But I prefer to get:

```
>>> np.datetime64('2012-01-01T00:00Z')
Out[110]: numpy.datetime64('2012-01-01T00:00+0000')
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code? Which date method are you using? Why use a numpy method, not python's?

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(formatter={'datetime':np.datetime_as_string})
>>> print np.array(['2012-01-02T01:02Z'], dtype='datetime64')
[2012-01-02T01:02Z]
```

The only problem with this is that the scalar is still printed in local timezone:

```
>>> print np.array(['2012-01-02T01:02Z'], dtype='datetime64')[0]
2012-01-02T03:02+0200
```